# PyQt mouse events for QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, pyqt, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to get the coordinates of various mouse events from a QGraphicsView, but I can't figure out how to trigger them. In the end, I want to add a picture to the graphicsView and then draw on top of it.

Ideally I would want the coordinates to have an origin in the top left

```
0,0--------------------
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

test.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


class test(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        self.connect(self.ui.graphicsView, QtCore.SIGNAL("mousePressEvent()"), self.mouse_pressed)
        self.connect(self.ui.graphicsView, QtCore.SIGNAL("mouseMoveEvent()"), self.mouse_moved)
        self.connect(self.ui.graphicsView, QtCore.SIGNAL("mouseReleaseEvent()"), self.mouse_released)

        self.ui.show()

    def mouse_pressed(self):
        p = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        print "pressed here: " + p.x() + ", " + p.y()

    def mouse_moved(self):
        p = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        print "moved here: " + p.x() + ", " + p.y()

    def mouse_released(self):
        p = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        print "released here: " + p.x() + ", " + p.y()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

EDIT:

this seems to work. the ellipse is no longer moveable, as the click event seems to take over. any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


class graphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(graphicsScene, self).__init__ (parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        position = QtCore.QPointF(event.scenePos())
        print "pressed here: " + str(position.x()) + ", " + str(position.y())
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        position = QtCore.QPointF(event.scenePos())
        print "moved here: " + str(position.x()) + ", " + str(position.y())
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        position = QtCore.QPointF(event.scenePos())
        print "released here: " + str(position.x()) + ", " + str(position.y())
        self.update()


class test(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        self.scene = graphicsScene()
        self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        e = self.scene.addEllipse(10,10,100,100, pen, brush)
        e.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)

        self.ui.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mousePressEvent` and other methods are not slots. You can't use `connect` on those methods. You need to install an event filter on your view's `viewport()` and catch events in your widget's `eventFilter` method.

See [Event Filters](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).

Comment: I think you mean: "you *can't* use `connect`" on those methods. Also, it's easier and cleaner to just override `mousePressEvent()` than it is to install an event filter.

Comment: It would require OP to subclass `QGraphicsView` and promote the view to this subclass in the UI file. That is an overcomplication. Subclassing `QGraphicsView` would be wise if one want to change view's behavior and reuse that class in several different places. I assume that this is not required in simple cases.

Comment: I think I did as you suggested. Any ideas on why coloring my ellipse doesn't work?

Comment: `QColor.red` and `QColor.blue` are functions. You need to use `Qt.red` and `Qt.blue` enum values instead.

Comment: brilliant. last question I hope. Any easy way to keep the ellipse movable?

Comment: I lied. also, how would I filter mouse click events for only left clicks? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To keep the ellipse movable you need to pass the event to the parent. For example for the mouseMoveEvent, at the end of the method you need to add this line:

```
super(graphicsScene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```